# concat two strings and put smaller string at first in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, concatenation, varchar

for concating two varchars from columns A and B ,like "1923X" and "11459" with the hashtag, while I always want the smallest string become at first, what should I do in SQL server query?

**inputs:**
Two Columns

A="1923X"

B="11459"

**procedure:**

while we are checking two inputs from right to left, in this example the second character value in B (1) is smaller than the second character in A (9) so B is smaller.

**result:** new column C

"11459#1923X"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Original answer:**

If you need to order the input strings, not only by second character, `STRING_AGG()` is also an option:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(5) = '1923X'
DECLARE @b varchar(5) = '11459'

SELECT STRING_AGG(v.String, '#') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.String) AS Result
FROM (VALUES (@a), (@b)) v (String)
```

Output:

```
Result
11459#1923X
```

**Update:**

You changed the requirements (now the strings are stored in two columns), so you need a different statement:

```
SELECT 
   A, 
   B, 
   C = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(v.String, '#') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.String)
      FROM (VALUES (A), (B)) v (String)
   )
FROM (VALUES ('1923X', '11459')) t (a, b)
```

Comment: what about the scenario that inputs and outputs are sql columns?

Comment: @Omk, please, do __not__ change the requirements in the question. (SO is not a free coding service, so prepare carefully your questions). In case of a table you need a different statement.